# Using image_replacer.js

Tags: javascript, css

Working with different resolution images I have recently come across image_replacer.js by Apple. However, I'm experiencing issues straight away when using it.

After having referenced the latest jquery library I reference image_replacer.js like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/local/path/to/image_replacer.js"></script>
```

but looking in the Inspector I'm getting the following error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined"

Anyone know what silly mistake I'm making?

Thanks

Comment: did you just add the replacer.js? Did you think about changing some html?

Comment: I just have a basic "shell" html page set up for testing. What do you mean by "changing some html"?

Comment: can anyone replicate this issue?

Comment: Maybe just try http://retinajs.com/ ?